# BOSS RC-300: how to record from AUX?

Tags: recording, aux-sends

Is there the possibility to record from AUX (phone, etc.) into a track in the RC-300? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question.

Comment: Closing - please read the manual first, and then ask here if the manual doesn't cover what you need. In this case it is in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there the possibility to record from AUX (phone, etc.) into a track in the RC-300?

Yes. It tells you that on page 1 of the [manual](https://www.boss.info/uk/support/by_product/rc-300/owners_manuals/). You should read it.

In fact, you should read the manual multiple times. Experiment and try out each feature (one at a time) until you learn how they work. This device is more like a musical instrument than a conventional piece of recording equipment. Like a musical instrument you should practise using it over and over again until you commit all the desired features to muscle memory.

Stack Exchange is not an alternative to studying the manual for your equipment. If you find something you can't understand after trying it out and looking online for alternative explanations then, but only then, you're welcome to ask here.

Comment: Thanks. However, in the manual I couldn't find the settings I must configure on my lapop. For instance, I noticed that if I set up INPUT = RC300 and OUTPUT = RC300, I can't record anything.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Under USB Audio on p.36 the manual states "You can play your computer’s sounds through the RC-300, or record the RC-300’s sounds into your computer." Perhaps simultaneous input and output isn't supported. That's why I suggested experimenting with each feature to see how it works. I don't have one of these devices myself. You can learn from people who do have one by searching for RC-300 forums.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Also make sure you've studied the notes on the [driver download page](https://www.boss.info/uk/support/by_product/rc-300/updates_drivers/) for your laptop's specific OS AND any readme file contained in the download.